# Converting AWS JSON output to CSV using jq

Tags: json, csv, jq

I am working on a script to combine my AWS Security Groups and Instances so I can have a consolidated list that looks something like this, in Excel/CSV format:

```
Security Groups | Security Group Name | Instances | Rules | Source
SG1             | GroupName           | Instance1 | :80   | 0.0.0.0\0
                |                     | Instance2 | :443  | 0.0.0.0\0
```

Please note I am VERY new to jq, and really have just been fumbling in the dark.

I use a series of API calls and jq to format my data, but my last string is formatted as flat json.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

### Get ALL data for all Instances
all_instances=$(aws ec2 describe-instances \
--query 'Reservations[].Instances[]' \
--profile dev)

### Get Only the Instance ID's
instanceids=$(aws ec2 describe-instances \
--query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' \
--output text \
--profile dev)

### Get all data from Security Groups
all_securitygroups="$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups --profile dev)"

### Match the Instances to the SG's, and pull the IP Rules as well
for instance in $instanceids; do
instance_sgids=$(echo $all_instances|jq -r "map(select(.InstanceId == \"$instance\"))[].SecurityGroups[].GroupId")
  for sg in $instance_sgids; do
    rules=$(echo $all_securitygroups|jq -r "map(select(.[].GroupId == \"$sg\"))[]" )

### Convert that silly Json to beautiful csv...
newrules=$(echo $rules|jq --compact-output --raw-output '{SGID: .[].GroupId, Description: .[].Description,Protocol: .[].IpPermissions[].IpProtocol, Port: .[].IpPermissions[].FromPort, CIDR: .[].IpPermissions[].IpRanges[].CidrIp} | flatten | @csv')

#flattenrules=$(echo $rules|jq -r [{ .Description } + (IpPermissions[] | { FromPort } + (IpRanges[] | {CidrIp}))])

echo "SecurityGroup, Name, Port, Source" > ~/Documents/output.csv
echo "$newrules" | sort | uniq >> ~/Documents/output.csv

  done
done
```

This gets me oh so close, but I just can't seem to figure the last leg out. I have the instance ID's, and now I have all of the SG information. My problem now finding a way to output it in the format I describe above...

I know I am probably missing something simple, but would love if any of you jq/shell guru's could point me in the right direction. I've seen other questions here that mention using Perl and other languages, but I would really like to keep this within jq/shell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The good news is that this can all be done using jq. Indeed, I doubt you even need use the shell to execute the inner "for" loop; you might not even need the "shell" for the outer "for" loop.  If you could tell us a bit more about "$all_instances" and "$all_securitygroups", it would be easier to help you.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi peak, thanks for responding. So I made some progress yesterday using jqplay.com, and have the data I want now. My final hurdle is getting the data formatted as I describe at the top of my Question. I don't know if formatting the JQ and joining it differently via shell is the way forward, or what.

I know my question took a bit of a pivot, but I am still trying to accomplish the same goal.

Any and all inputs are appreciated!!!

Comment: Without your data, I can only offer a gentle reminder that to use `@csv` fruitfully, you have to arrange that its input is an array of scalars.  This can very easily be done in jq.  By the way, if I were you, I'd try to use `@tsv` if at all possible instead of `@csv`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to do much without some actual data but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704642/8379597) to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543318/parse-aws-cli-output-security-groups-with-jq) produces a report from the output of

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-0000001 sg-0000002
```

Perhaps it may be of help.